# I don't know why there is an error in the code. List to detect remainder of 3 and sort into other lists

Tags: python, list, if-statement

Below is my code and error which I get on running :

```
src_list = [12,45,34,13,100,24,56,74,109]
n = 0
a_list = []
b_list = []
c_list = []
for i in range(len(src_list)):
    if src_list[n] % 3 = 0:
        a_list.append(src_list[n])
    elif src_list[n] % 3 = 1:
        b_list.append(src_list[n])
    else:
        c_list.append(src_list[n])
    n = n+1
print(a_list)
print(b_list)
print(c_list)
```

Error : `SyntaxError:bad input on line 7`

Comment: For equality comparison between 2 elements, you need to use double equal sign `==`. Here you are using single `=`.  You can try out the below answer.

Answer (score 0):

In the `if` and `elif` condition line, you are not comparing the values. Instead you are trying to assign a value with single `=` operator sign.

For comparisons you need 2 `==` signs.

Here is how you should do it :

```
src_list = [12,45,34,13,100,24,56,74,109]
n = 0
a_list = []
b_list = []
c_list = []
for i in range(len(src_list)):
    if src_list[n] % 3 == 0:
        a_list.append(src_list[n])
    elif src_list[n] % 3 == 1:
        b_list.append(src_list[n])
    else:
        c_list.append(src_list[n])
    n = n+1
print(a_list)
print(b_list)
print(c_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is not using a comparison `==`.
Also there are several other things which would make your code more *pythonic:*

```
src_list = [12,45,34,13,100,24,56,74,109]
a_list = []
b_list = []
c_list = []
for n, i in enumerate(src_list):
    if src_list[n] % 3 == 0:
        a_list.append(src_list[n])
    elif src_list[n] % 3 == 1:
        b_list.append(src_list[n])
    else:
        c_list.append(src_list[n])
print(a_list)
print(b_list)
print(c_list)
```

1. You don't need `range(len(...))` to iterate over your list. A list can be iterated with `for i in list_name:`
2. You can use enumerate to generate an index. With this you don't need to manually increment your `n`with every step.